# How do I optimize searching 3,000 records for an email that matches one on a lead?

Tags: apex, soql, map, performance

**Scenario**

A New Lead is inserted, if it matches criteria, the lead ownerid is Updated based on an email field on the lead.

**Problem**

Write code that takes the email address and queries all Users for one which has an email matching the lead field.

**Question**

How do I optimize this Operation?  I currently am doing it with 3 nested for loop.  I would like to do this using a map< email,User> so I can take advantage of the loopups instead of raw iteration. This method is inside a trigger helper class. **Newlead** is a a map of newleads.

```
    Public static void updateOwnerIdForPartner() {
    List<lead> leadsToUpdate = new list<lead>();
    List<String> emails = new list<String>();


    for(Lead lead: newLead) {

        if(lead.Sales_Rep_Email__c != null && lead.recordtypeid == '012C0000000M000000' && lead.LeadSource == 'Partner') {
            leadsToUpdate.add(lead);
            emails.add(lead.Sales_Rep_Email__c);
        }
    }
    if(leadsToUpdate.size() > 0) {

        for(List<user> users: [SELECT Id, email FROM user WHERE email IN :emails]) {
            for(User user : Users) {
                for(Lead lead : leadsToUpdate) {
                    if(lead.Sales_Rep_Email__c == user.email) {
                        lead.OwnerId = user.id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use hard-coded Ids... Regardless, where are you getting `newLeads` or `leadsToUpdate`? You should avoid using `static` properties to track stateful data.

Comment: lead trigger fires helper method on before insert of lead.  Trigger passes trigger.newmap to the helper class before hand. Which is what newleads is the recipient of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the map is quite simple. It's like any other map, nothing special here.

```
Map<String, List<Lead>> emailToLeads = new Map<String, List<Lead>>();
for (Lead record : someCollection)
{
    if (!emailToLeads.containsKey(record.Email))
        emailToLeads.put(record.Email, new List<Lead>());
    emailToLeads.get(record.Email).add(record);
}
```

Note that since multiple records can have the same `Email`, you use `List<Lead>` as the map value, rather than a single record. Note also that this field is not unique on `User` either, so if multiple have the same `Email`, you will have arbitrarily assign one of them.

Comment: Map keys are case sensitive, will it be good to lowercase all email id and then set them as keys?

Comment: Fair point. Yeah making them lower case would be a good idea.